# List of most executed contracts

Tags: statistics

As a newbie in the field I would like to know how can I find the most often executed smart contracts in the ethereum chain? Do I need to run a full node for that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A good start is [ETH Gas Station's Gas Burner's list](https://www.ethgasstation.info/gasguzzlers.php).

You can craft your own queries using [Google's BigQuery Ethereum dataset](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics).